# What's the 'generate grease pencil' command in render view?

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

[image]

I saw something amazing in render view.

It was a command, 'generate greae pencil' in above picture.

But despite the execution of the order, nothing was done except that the name of g.p.object had been added in outliner(see below picture).

[image]

I thought that if I had done that command, a g.p.object like rendering image would appear in 3d veiwport.

But I could not find anything.

How can I use that command?

Comment: @susu Could you show me the resulting g.p.object? I have done as you taught me, but there's nothing but a g.p.object's origin

Comment: @susu thank you for good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an image in the image editor and create a grease pencil object with it.

In the image editor create a new image (Image>New).

Change to Draw Mode.

Create your drawing.

Select Image>Generate Grease Pencil Object.

Switch to the 3d viewport, the grease pencil object should appear. The grease pencil object will be created with the lower left corner at the place where the 3d cursor is.

[image]